# Enforcing pointer to pointer type at compile time

Tags: c++, pointers, readability, type-safety

I have got a deserialization scenario for an object hierarchy, in which most objects contain pointers to other objects, but don't own them.

I am trying to implement a two-step process in which:

1. Objects are created, `Register(Object* pObject)`ed to an ID, data is read. Pointer members are serialized as unique IDs, so upon reading them back, I `RegisterResolver(int id, Object** ppMember)`s.
2. Resolvers are processed: IDs are looked up and the correct address is written to the address that is `*ppMember` (notice the dereferencing).

The problem:

- I want to enforce that only pointers to objects of or derived from a certain `Base` class be registered, however `Derived**` can't be converted to `Base**`.
- I want to *at least* avoid ambiguity when using `void*` (not `void**`) that `Derived**` / `Base**` can be both converted to, but then so can `Derived*` / `Base*`.

In the following scenario:

```
struct A: public Serialized
{
  int blah;
};

struct B: public Serialized
{
  float fBlah;
  A*    pTarget;
};

B myB;
```

If the interface is `RegisterResolver(int id, void* ppObject)`, there's no guarantee that client code won't pass `myB.pTarget` instead of `&myB.pTarget`.

What can I do to improve the [type-]safety and readability of this solution?

(The target platforms are x86 and ARM.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the original issue was also concerning readability and I wanted to minimize potentially confusing parameters on the interface, I've iterated on [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt)'s answer and ended up with this:

```
template<typename T>
void RegisterResolver(int id, T** ppObject)
{
  // assert(ppObject != 0);
  Base* pBase(*ppObject); // not used

  // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A template should help.  How about

```
template<typename T>
void RegisterResolver(int id, T** ppObject, Base* extra = (T*)0);
```

This permits an argument of any type `Derived**` for which there is an implicit conversion from `Derived*` to `Base*`.